# Roblox Forum, Web Scraping App (Android) Questions

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, roblox

I've been waiting for an idea and I think I finally have one. I am going to attempt to make a Android App using Web Scraping that will allow me to navigate and use the forums on Roblox (.com if you really want to look it up) better than I can now. Not only are the forums pretty bad in general but they are even worse on my Android Device (Samsung Galaxy Player). Can anyone give me an pointers or advice? I'm not sure what libraries I should use... This is my first big attempt at coding :)

Oh, Obviously I would want to give it a feature to reply to posts but I'm not sure how login for that type of thing would work...

EDIT: I got the idea from this application: [GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrewshu.android.reddit&hl=en), [Github](https://github.com/talklittle/reddit-is-fun)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look up how to get the data from the website, and you should also make sure that you understand html. You also need a simple way to handle html.

- Get the page (use the example in the question): [Read data from webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232535/read-data-from-webpage)
- A bit about html: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
- Handle html: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

To login you should do a post request with the login information to the standard login page, then you keep the cookie that were generated and pass it with your other requests.

- Little about handle cookies: [Java: Handling cookies when logging in with POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047363/java-handling-cookies-when-logging-in-with-post)

Some things you also might want to think about:

- Linear or branched view of posts in the forum?
- Should you get a message if someone post a new post?
- A own search function?
- Signature?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSOUP libaray of java ,you can easily parse the html data through this library. Example: In doc object you are getting complete web page

```
File input = new File(url);
Document doc = null;
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements headlinesCat1 = doc.select("div[class=abc");
```